# AngularJS - Dependency injection in services, factories, filters etc

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, angularjs

So I have some plugins and libraries I want to use in my angular app and (currently) I am simply referencing those functions/methods as they were intended in 99% of apps in a way that completely ignores dependency injection.

I have (for example) the javascript library "MomentJS" which deals with formatting and validating dates and I have uses for it throughout my app in controllers, services and filters. The way that I've learned (using AngularJS) is to create a service that references the function (and it's methods) and inject that service into my controllers, which works great.

The problem is that I really need to reference this library in all different kinds of components from services to filters to controllers and everything else. So, I guess my question is how do you do dependency injection in filters, services and everything else that isn't a controller?

Is this possible? Is this even beneficial?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Yes you can use dependency injection for filters and directives

Ex:

Filter:

```
app.filter('<filter>', ['$http', function(http){
    return function(data){
    }
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('<directive>', ['$http', function(http){
    return {
        ....
    }
}]);
```

Service:

```
app.factory('<service>', ['$http', function(http) {
  var shinyNewServiceInstance;
  return shinyNewServiceInstance;
}]);
```

Comment: Is there any way to bend syntax to inject dependencies into a provider? I need either: a provider that I can inject deps into, or a factory/service that I can inject into a config block(?)

Comment: @Cody Services and factories _are_ providers. Also `.config()` handles Dependency injection in the exact same way as the examples above.

Comment: @KevinBeal so for any method of `module`, (i.e. `config, `run`, `controller`, etc), you pass an array with the dependencies and a handler function, and the dependencies will then be injected to the handler function. Am I right? Thank you!

Comment: @pilau anywhere a method expects a function you can, yes. You can even do it for the controller method that's in the return value of a directive. (Anywhere there is dependency injection).

Comment: @KevinBeal I am asking specifically because at the bottom of [this page](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/04/30/angular-abstractions-the-application.aspx) it says "Passing the dependencies parameter again will wipe out the module definition and start over". So is Mr. Allen wrong?

Comment: @pilau No, he's totally right. I'm not talking about injecting modules. I'm talking about injecting services and things like you would do in the above examples. So the `.module()` method is an exception in this case.

Comment: @KevinBeal I am sorry, I am not a native English speaker, and I am a bit lost and confused. Will using different dependencies in `config` and `run` blocks overwrite the dependencies for the module or not? Will it overwrite the dependencies in *preceding* `config`/`run` blocks? Or, as common sense dictates, are the dependencies injected only to the appropriate handlers?

Answer (score 20):

For the sake of completeness, here is a service example with injection:

```
app.service('<service>', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.foo = function() { ... }
}]);
```

Comment: As at this time I seem unable to inject a controller into a service - at least not my own custom one. I really shouldn't be here but I cant see a way to make a modal directive work which sits outside of the controller that instigates it popping up.
I created a service to try and do the two way communication thinkingn the service could inject both controllers but alas.. what would be the best way to achieve this. I would like to ask questions here but it seems to be blocked for some reason so I can only comment on similar things.

Comment: You really need to make a question, preferably with a [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/) of your code.

Comment: I would love to be able to write questions - it seems this site once you get blocked for asking too much it blocks you forever. In short I think you cant inject controllers into things (which just sounds daft anyway)
So I created service and getter setter and then watch this for changes in the controllers that need to subscribe to the updates. This worked and allows me controller to controller coms.

Answer (score 7):

While the already existing answers are correct and working, john papas angular style guide favors the use of the `$inject` service in [Y091](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y091):

Filter:

```
app.filter('<filter>', MyFilter);
MyFilter.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyFilter() {
  return function(data) {
  }
}
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('<directive>', MyDirective);
MyDirective.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyDirective() {
  return {
    ...
  }
}
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('<factory>', MyFactory);
MyFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyFactory() {
  var shinyNewServiceInstance;
  return shinyNewServiceInstance;
}
```

Service:

```
app.service('<service>', MyService);
MyService.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyService() {
  this.foo = foo;
  function foo(){
    ...
  }
}
```