# How to inject dependencies in angular services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

```
function Greeter(a) {
  this.greet = function() {

    //How should I declare the dependency for e.g. $http so that I do a GET request here?
    return 'Hello ' + a;
  }
}


provider.service('greeter', Greeter);
```

If I am using the above format, where I create a class definition and then using the `.service` notation, declare the service, how do I use for e.g. `$http` or other dependencies?

This 
[AngularJS - Dependency injection in services, factories, filters etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457720/angularjs-dependency-injection-in-services-factories-filters-etc)

provides a solution when the service is defined where it is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's [injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector) injects based on argument name. If you pass the name of a registered module to it it will find it and will inject it automatically.

```
function Greeter($http) { // the injector will inject $http here
  this.greet = function() {

    //How should I declare the dependency for e.g. $http so that I do a GET request here?
    return 'Hello ' + a;
  }
}
```

Note that this is not safe for minification, if you intend to minify your code use *that* syntax instead (and pass an array).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this (this is also minification safe):

```
define([ 'components' ], function() {
  angular.module('components.services').provider('dateFormatService', function() {        
    var self = this;

    self.$get = ['aService', 'bService', function (aService, bService) {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if you define class definition beforehand or use anonymous function, you can annotate dependencies in array:

```
function Greeter(b) {
   //provider will inject 'a' service as variable of any name, in this case it's 'b'
}

provider.service('greeter', ['a', Greeter]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `.$inject` property:

```
function Greeter(a) {...}
Greeter.$inject = ['a'];
```